# How can three or more strings be concatenated in R

Tags: r

In PHP I can use the dot to paste strings:

```
$path = "/path/to/directory/";
$extension =".txt";
$filecounter = $i; // from some loop for creating multiple files
$file = $path . "filename_". $filecounter . $extension;
```

How can I do something similar in R?

```
path <- "/path/to/directory/"
extension <- ".txt"
filecounter <- i
file <- paste(path, paste(paste("filename", $filecounter, sep =""), extension, sep =""), sep ="")
```

seems like a lot of extra typing for such a simple task.

Comment: You can save some typing with `paste0(path, "file.txt")`.

Comment: Nice. Why don't you give that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Ok, I added an answer.

Comment: Not a duplicate, because I don't want to be restricted to only two strings.

Comment: Are you telling me you haven't even looked at the documentation for paste?  There is no restriction - just add more stuff into paste. `paste("Seriously", "give", "it", "a", "try...")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In recent R versions, you can save some typing with :

```
paste0(path, "file.txt")
```

`paste0(...)` is equivalent to `paste(..., sep="")`, and slightly more efficient.

Comment: I edited my question. Can you come up with a simple solution for three or more strings, not just two?

Comment: Please look at @Dason comment.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `file.path` which Construct the path to a file from components in a platform-independent way.

```
path = "/path/to/directory/"
file = "file.txt"

file.path(path,file)
```

Comment: +1 for the better tool

Comment: I edited my question. Can you come up with a simple solution for three or more strings, not just two?

Comment: @what you can replace `file` in my solution by `paste0(filecounter,extension)`.

Answer (score 4):

You should really use `file.path` and `paste` since it's fast and platform independent. (seealso `tools::file_ext`, `tools::file_path_sans_ext`), but below is a little function that is intended for Linux or Mac systems that *might* come in handy.  I don't use it very often because if I share my code, I either have to give the user this function or a personal package that contains it, so I usually end up editing the code to use `file.path` and it turns out to be less work to just not use this function to begin with.

```
> fpath(path, "filename", extension)
[1] "/path/to/directory/filename.txt"
```

---

```
#' create a filepath
#'
#' This just pastes together \code{dir} and \code{file} and optionally 
#' \code{ext}.  It is intended for Mac or Linux systems. 
#' @param dir character string of directory (with or without trailing slash)
#' @param file character string of filename (with or without extension)
#' @param ext Optional. character file extension. (with or without leading dot)
#' @return character string representing a filepath
#' @examples
#' fpath("path/to", "file", "csv")
#' fpath("path/to/", "file.csv", ".csv") 
#' #knows not to duplicatate the "/" or the ".csv"
#' fpath('path/to', 'file.csv')
#' fpath("file", ext="csv") #knows that dir is missing
#' fpath("", "file", "txt") # no leading forward slash if dir == ""
#' @export
fpath <- function(dir, file, ext) {
    lchar <- function(x) substr(x, nchar(x), nchar(x)) #last char of string
    fl <- if (missing(file)) {
      dir
    } else {
        if (missing(dir) || dir == "") {
            file
        } else {
            dir <- if (substr(dir, nchar(dir), nchar(dir)) != "/") { 
                paste(dir, "/", sep="") 
            } else dir
            file <- gsub("^/+", "", file) # remove leading forward slashes from file names
            paste(dir, file, sep="")
            #TODO: should figure out how to throw an error (or allow it to work) if called like 
            #      fpath("ftp:/", "/ftp.domain.com") or fpath('http:/', '/www.domain.com')
        }
    }
    if (lchar(fl) == "/") stop("'file' should not end with a forward slash")
    if (!missing(ext)) {
        ext <- if (substr(ext, 1, 1) != ".") {
            paste(".", ext, sep="")
        } else ext
        if (substr(fl, nchar(fl) - nchar(ext) + 1, nchar(fl)) != ext) {
            fl <- paste(fl, ext, sep="")
        }
    }
    fl
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want things to look a *lot* like PHP you can define your own infix operator and set it equal to `paste()`:

```
"%.%" <- paste
"a" %.% "b" %.% "c" %.% "d"
## [1] "a b c d"
```

Of course you could use `paste0` instead if you wanted concatenated rather than space-separated strings.

Answer (score 2):

Or as an alternative to `paste0`:

```
sprintf("%s/%s", path, 'file.txt')
```

for more entries in a string, @BenBolker suggested:

```
sprintf("%s/%s.%s", path, file, extension)
```

Comment: I edited my question. Can you come up with a simple solution for three or more strings, not just two?

Comment: `sprintf("%s/%s.%s", path, file, extension)`